# How to use single click event for multiple button id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I am having two buttons with id `frm_submit1` and `frm_submit2`

```
<button type="button" id="frm_submit1">Click Me 1!</button>
<button type="button" id="frm_submit2">Click Me 2!</button>
```

In jquery, I need to do same onclick event for both the buttons. For one button (frm_submit1) click, I used like below. How can I use for multiple buttons?

```
$(document).on('click', '#frm_submit1', function(event) {
});
```

I used this, but didn't worked! Any idea?

```
$("#frm_submit1, #frm_submit2").click(function (e) {  
// do something  
});
```

Comment: With the selector `$("#frm_submit1, #frm_submit2")`, you achieved the objective of attaching the same onclick handler to the two buttons. So what is it that still doesn't work?

Comment: This will work. But, I don't know the reason. I think problem with my code. Let me check. I am using onsenui Framework. So all the pages will be stored in a stack. So that might be a problem

Comment: onsenui is pretty arcane. You'll need to provide a link and include the `onsen-ui` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just separate the IDs by a comma:

```
$(document).on('click', '#frm_submit1, #frm_submit2', function(event) {
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yfrvhxkj/)**

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - Perhaps they're added dynamically to the page.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Yes, why?

Comment: I'd prefer using a class as one single selector

Comment: I am using onsenui. so pages are in stack. So that might be a problem

Comment: This is a bad answer because it does not explain why this would work... it has nothing to do with IDs being separated by commas. And this is placing the listener on the `document` something that should be placed on the closest static parent -1

Comment: @Phil - First off, not a bad answer. I simply re-used the example the OP posted which he said worked for a single element, and extended it. While I agree with you that `document` is a worst case selector, the OP has provided no other details.

Comment: This is working fine for me..Is this a bad practice? I mean using document

Comment: @UIDesigner - Nope, but it's not the most efficient. Ideally you want to select an ancestor element, other than document, that's closer in the DOM to your buttons that exists when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It's better for this case to use class :

```
$(".classForButtons").click(function () {  
        // do something  
   });
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use the button element as the selector instead. That will run on click on all buttons. Best would be do declare a class on the buttons that you want to use it on and then use the class as the selector instead.

```
$("button").click(function (e) {  
    // do something  
});
```

Comment: are you talking seriously?

Comment: what is this? Mr.user2952238

Comment: Yes, why? This buttons could be added to the DOM dynamically or whatever. That info is not provided. ALSO: "Best would be do declare a class on the buttons that you want to use it on and then use the class as the selector instead."

Comment: So, if they are dynamically added, does attaching a click handler to do just one specific thing, to all buttons on the page solve the problem? You need some revision

Comment: If a class i s added, yes.

Comment: so in html page are many button added, your code has been add event to all button in page, it's unnecessary..